# how to calculate duration between two events Splunk

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-calculation

I need to find the duration between two events. I went over the solutions on [splunk](/questions/tagged/splunk) and Stack Overflow, but still can't get the calculation.

Both `sentToSave` and `SaveDoc` have the time stamp already formatted, which is why I used the case function. I am able to see the fields populate with their time stamps, but I am not able to get the `Duration` field to populate the duration - it simply does not populate at all.

Need some help on how to get the `Duration` - any advice? Here is my search:

```
(index=souce1 dept=qvc event="sentToSave") OR (index=source dept=save area=saveDoc)
| eval saveDocTime=case(area="saveDoc", TimeStamp), sentToSaveTime=case(event="sentToSave", TimeStamp)
| eval Duration=saveDocTime-sentToSaveTime
| stats values(Duration) as Duration earliest(sentToSaveTime) as sentToSaveTime latest(saveDocTime) as saveDocTime  by emailRequest
| where isNotNull(sentToSaveTime) AND isNotNull(saveDocTime)
```

Comment: Could you please add sample events to your question?

Answer (score 3):

Timestamps must be in integer (epoch) form to be compared.  Use the [`strptime` function](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/DateandTimeFunctions#strptime.28X.2CY.29) to convert them from strings to integers and then you can subtract them.

As @Anant Naugai said, if you provide some sample events then we can be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

The reason `Duration` is not populating, I suspect without data, is that the `saveDocTime` and `sentToSaveTime` fields are from different events. (Your first line implies as much with different indexes).

Since `eval` works on each result in parallel, `Duration` as it is currently calculated will always be undefined since you are always trying to perform a calculation with a value that doesn't exist (one or the other depending on which kind of event it's attempting.

Now your `stats` event pulls the fields together into a single event for each `emailRequest`. So if you move your eval for calculating Duration to after the `stats` command you'll have a duration.