# How to show the time difference between two events in a Splunk join query?

Tags: splunk

Consider the following log data,

```json
{"level":"info","msg":"Enqueued a recurring task","time":"2022-04-01T18:46:22.854684-07:00","uuid":"4e9fc098-f611-4128-ae0b-2e6b9cb232c8"}
{"level":"info","msg":"Reported a result","path":"/results","time":"2022-04-01T18:46:22.955999-07:00","uuid":"4e9fc098-f611-4128-ae0b-2e6b9cb232c8"}
{"level":"info","msg":"Reported a result","path":"/results","time":"2022-04-01T18:46:23.056295-07:00","uuid":"4e9fc098-f611-4128-ae0b-2e6b9cb232c8"}
{"level":"info","msg":"Enqueued a recurring task","time":"2022-04-01T18:46:23.056376-07:00","uuid":"28e9bea9-5d0c-4dd5-af4f-c22944fc4fcd"}
```

It represents enqueuing a recurring task with a certain `uuid`, the results of which can be reported multiple times (or not at all) with the same `uuid`. I'm interested in determining the interval elapsed between when the task was enqueued and when the result was reported for the first time. So far, I can display the results this outer join table,

```
msg="Enqueued a recurring task" 
| join type=outer left=L right=R where L.uuid = R.uuid 
    [ search msg="Reported a result" | dedup uuid sortby +_time] 
| fillnull value="" 
| table _time, L.msg, L.uuid, R.msg, L.time, R.time
```

[image]

What I'd like for convenience is to add an additional column with the difference between `R.time` and `L.time`. As far as I can tell from [how to calculate duration between two events Splunk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66896889/how-to-calculate-duration-between-two-events-splunk), one way to do this is to use [strptime](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/DateandTimeFunctions#strptime.28X.2CY.29) to convert those time fields into time values and then determine their difference. However, the time of the events was already parsed when importing the data (as seen from the built-in `_time` field) so this seems inefficient to me. Is there a more efficient way?

### Update

Even the 'inefficient' method using `strptime` is proving tricky; I've added `eval` fields `t` to each of the searches,

```
msg="Enqueued a recurring task" 
| eval t=strptime(time, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%6N%:z") 
| join type=outer left=L right=R where L.uuid = R.uuid 
    [ search msg="Reported a result" 
    | dedup uuid sortby +_time 
    | eval t=strptime(time, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%6N%:z")]
| fillnull value="" 
| table _time, L.msg, L.uuid, R.msg, L.time, R.time, L.t, R.t, R.t-L.t
```

and it appears to parse the time correctly, yet the difference `R.t-L.t` shows up empty in the table:
[image]
Any idea why it's not showing the difference?

### Update 2

I've tried both of [RichG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2227420/richg)'s answers, but they both lead to the following error in Splunk:

> Error in 'eval' command: Type checking failed. '-' only takes numbers.

(See screenshots below). The way I'm running Splunk is with a Docker container,

```
docker run -p 8000:8000 -e "SPLUNK_START_ARGS=--accept-license" -e "SPLUNK_PASSWORD=supersecret" --name splunk splunk/splunk:latest
```

[image]

[image: The second one leads to the error]

### Update 3

I finally got this to work using RichG's updated answer, combining both an evaluated `strftime` field with a `diff` field where `R.t` and `L.t` are quoted:

```
msg="Enqueued a recurring task" 
| eval t=strptime(time, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%6N%:z") 
| join type=outer left=L right=R where L.uuid = R.uuid 
    [ search msg="Reported a result" 
    | dedup uuid sortby +_time 
    | eval t=strptime(time, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%6N%:z")]
| fillnull value="" 
| eval diff='R.t'-'L.t'
| table _time, L.msg, L.uuid, R.msg, L.time, R.time, L.t, R.t, diff
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time difference is empty in the table because the `table` command does not perform arithmetic.  You must calculate the difference in a separate `eval` and display the result in the table.

```
index=foo msg="Enqueued a recurring task" 
| eval t=strptime(time, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%6N%:z") 
| join type=outer left=L right=R where L.uuid = R.uuid 
    [ search index=foo msg="Reported a result" 
    | dedup uuid sortby +_time 
    | eval t=strptime(time, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%6N%:z")]
| fillnull value="" 
| eval diff='R.t' - 'L.t'
| table _time, L.msg, L.uuid, R.msg, L.time, R.time, L.t, R.t, diff
```

You should be able to use each event's `_time` field to avoid having to parse the time field.

```
index=foo msg="Enqueued a recurring task" 
| join type=outer left=L right=R where L.uuid = R.uuid 
    [ search index=foo msg="Reported a result" 
    | dedup uuid sortby +_time ]
| fillnull value="" 
| eval diff='R._time' - 'L._time'
| table _time, L.msg, L.uuid, R.msg, L.time, R.time, L.t, R.t, diff
```

Comment: I've actually tried this but I get a Splunk type check error, `'-' only takes numbers.`. This does surprise me because your answer is similar to https://community.splunk.com/t5/Splunk-Search/eval-Time-difference/m-p/109208, for example. Any idea what the (remaining) issue might be?

Comment: Try quoting the field names.  `| eval diff='R._time' - 'L._time'`

Comment: That seems to get ride of the syntax error, but the `diff` column in the resulting table is empty.

Comment: I wonder if `eval` doesn't work right with `join`'s left and right options.  Try renaming them. `| rename 'R._time' as R_time, 'L._time' as L_time | eval diff = R_time - L_time`.

Comment: As I've updated in the question, your first answer with `strptime` and quoted fields in the diff works! (I tried using `rename` without `strptime` as you suggested above, but that still gives rise to an empty `diff` column, so I still haven't managed to use the fact that Splunk already parsed the timestamps when it loaded the data, but at least it works).

Answer (score 1):

Fairly confident something akin to this should work (without using `join`:

```
index=ndx sourtype=srctp uuid=* msg=*
| stats min(_time) as first_time max(_time) as last_time earliest(msg) as first_msg latest(msg) as last_msg by uuid
| eval diff_seconds=last_time-first_time
| eval first_time=strftime(first_time,"%c"), last_time=strftime(last_time,"%c")
```

This approach will presume that `_time` has been set properly in the sourcetype's `props.conf`, but if it has, this gets you what you're looking for in one pass.

Comment: That works! The only thing is that it appears to assume that the only logs with a `msg` field are the ones I'm interested in, `Enqueued a recurring task` and `Reported a result`, respectively. In my real example, however, there are many other logs with a `msg` field and I would like to filter the results down to those values specifically.

Comment: @KurtPeek - then do something like `(msg="enqueued a recurring task" OR msg="reported a result")` instead :)